# RoR - Carrierwave + S3, storing image urls via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm working on a system for **uploading images** to **S3** with **Carrierwave**. 
There are two possible ways to upload image:

- Upload from file to S3
- **Manual upload via API**

Upload from file is working great. File is formated in base64 and sent to server which is procesing and uploading with carrierwave to S3.

**My questions starts here**, with manual upload. Frontend is uploading images to S3 and sending image urls to server.
How do I store that urls with carrierwave? Like a simple string to image column or there is something more?

So, how and where do I save S3 image url ?

---

I tried something like this:

```
ElementImage.create(:image => image_params[:image_url])
```

Also with `image.url`, `image.base_path`

Comment: check this out -https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct

Comment: thanks @ChenKinnrot , but not solving my current problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for:  [CarrierWave docs for "Upload remote image urls to your seedfile"](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Upload-remote-image-urls-to-your-seedfile)

---

"...you can easily upload remote images by using `remote_[your_image_attribute_name]_url`"

So, in my case:

```
ElementImage.create!(remote_image_url: image_params[:image_url])
```

CarrierWave should throw an error if the url of the location is invalid.